# How to set a conditional DEFAULT value to a column in oracle without using triggers?

Tags: oracle, database-design, constraints, default

How to set a conditional DEFAULT value to a column in oracle without using triggers?
I want to achieve following needs:

1. If "flag1"=1 then Default value to column Newfield must be "4".
2. If "flag1"=2 then Default value to column Newfield must be "5".

Comment: What's wrong with using a trigger?

Answer (score 5):

That's what triggers are for. Use them.

Answer (score 4):

A column DEFAULT is not allowed to reference another column, so this is not possible.

You could perhaps just let the default remain as NULL, and then have a view to adjust it like:

```
create view mytable_view as
select flag1, nvl(newfield, case flag1 when 1 then 4
                                       when 2 then 5
                            end) as newfield
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 1):

If column `Newfield` does not need to be updateable, then you could simply implement it in a view, as Tony showed, or in 11g you could make it a virtual column.

Answer (score 0):

If 'flag' is something session (or statement) level then [SYS_CONTEXT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm) may be a way through. Possibly a BEFORE STATEMENT trigger if the issue is avoiding a context switch for every row inserted