# How can I change the default value for certain rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Fistly, I need to make all rows in a column called Mail_flag have a default of 'Y'. I did this already with the following line of code:

```
ALTER TABLE criminals
     MODIFY (Mail_flag DEFAULT 'Y');
```

Easy enough. But now, I need to make all rows that do NOT have a street address (where the column name is "street") have a default value of 'N'. I assumed the code would like something like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE criminals
     MODIFY (Mail_flag DEFAULT 'N')
     WHERE street = null;
```

However, I received an error message which said "Invalid Alter Table Option." I then tried an Update command, which also failed. Basically, I need two default values. One that is a 'Y', and one that is an 'N', only when a certain condition applies (the condition being that the street value is null). Please help! I've been struggling with this for 2 hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a conditional DEFAULT value to a column in oracle without using triggers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857715/how-to-set-a-conditional-default-value-to-a-column-in-oracle-without-using-trigg)

Comment: I think my question is actually much simpler than the question you referenced as a duplicate. The solution to that question was to use triggers, but we haven't even learned about triggers yet in my course, so I need a different solution. Thank you for trying to keep this website clutter free though :)

Answer (score 1):

> WHERE street = null;

That is so wrong. You don't understand what NULL value means. Though your alter statement won't be executing even if you fix it, but you shouldn't do it as it is wrong. The correct way to filter the rows is `where column IS NULL`

For your requirement, do a one time `update` :

```
update criminals
   Set mail_flag = 'N'
where street is null;
```

Then, implement a trigger to do the same update whenever it finds the old value as null.

I am having another thought now. Why do you want to update the column at all? So that, you could use the values in an operation or to display, isn't it? So, you can always use functions like `DECODE` and `NVL` to return the value `N` whenever column is null.

Comment: Well, this is for school, and we're creating a database for a city jail. I don't know anything about triggers or functions yet. But as far as I can tell, this exercise is to update the column so that criminals who have street addresses will be automatically flagged to receive mail updates of their hearing dates, sentencing, etc. And criminals who DON'T have mailing addresses won't receive information, as it would be a waste of time and money.

Comment: Hopefully you got your solution. For future, you can start reading about triggers and functions and other `database concepts`.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom McNish You have to know another thing `default` value always reflects on new row which you are trying to insert. I mean if you didnt pass any value to that particular column in which you are set to `default` it replaces default value instead of null

- Default doesnot works on existing rows which already have some data or null.
- Default always worked on newly inserting rows.

So for your existing condition....You have to update values using `update` query....

```
> update  table_name  
>       Set column_name = 'default_value' 
> where column_name is null;
```